# Java: use lambda expression in Handler.setFormatter

Tags: java, logging, lambda, handler

I use a Logger in my code (java.util.logging)
I create a Handler to add to the logger
I want to set the Formatter on this Handler
I can do it with an anonymous inner class, but I would like to replace that class with a lambda expression. I can't find out how to do that. Any suggestions?

Working code:

```
public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("KYCReviewSchedule");
Handler INFOHandler = new FileHandler(OUTPUTDIR + "INFO_logger.txt",true);

INFOConsoleHandler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter() {
    private static final String format = "[%1$tF %1$tT] [%2$-7s] %3$s %n";
    public String format(LogRecord lr) {
        return String.format(format,new Date(lr.getMillis()),
            lr.getLevel().getLocalizedName(),lr.getMessage())

    }
});
```

I would like to replace the last statement with a lambda expression like:

```
 INFOConsoleHandler.setFormatter(
    (lr)->  String.format("[%1$tF %1$tT] [%2$-7s] %3$s %n",
    lr.millis(),lr.getSourceMethodName(), lr.getLoggerName() , 
    lr.getLevel(), lr.getMessage() , lr.getThrown())
);
```

Comment: You can't. Formatter is a class. A lambda expression can only be used to implement a functional interface.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an adapter method to turn a lambda into a `SimpleFormatter` but you would need a functional interface:

```
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface LogFormatter {
    public String format(LogRecord lr);
}
```

The adapter method would look like this:

```
public static SimpleFormatter simpleFormat(LogFormatter formatter) {
    return new SimpleFormatter() {
        public String format(LogRecord lr) {
            return formatter.format(lr);
        }
    };
}
```

You could then invoke it like this:

```
INFOConsoleHandler.setFormatter(simpleFormat(
    lr -> String.format("[%1$tF %1$tT] [%2$-7s] %3$s %n",
        lr.millis(), lr.getSourceMethodName(), lr.getLoggerName(), 
        lr.getLevel(), lr.getMessage() , lr.getThrown())
));
```

It wouldn't provide any advantage if this is the only place where you do it, but if you're creating formatters in numerous places in your code and prefer defining them with lambdas, it could be worth it.

Comment: Thanx, indeed for my purpose that is not worth the trouble.